# Unique product groups (and semigroups)

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, ordered-groups

A group $G$ is called a u.p.-group (short for *unique product group*) if for all nonempty finite subsets $A,B\subseteq G$, there exists an element $g\in A \cdot B$ which can be uniquely written as a product $g=ab$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

My question is: Does there exist a u.p.-group (or even u.p.-semigroup) for which the corresponding property with three subsets $A,B,C$ doesn't hold?  Meaning, must it be the case that there is an element $g\in A\cdot B\cdot C$ which is uniquely represented in the form $g=abc$ for some $a\in A,b\in B,c\in C$?

Necessarily, such a group would not be (two-sided) orderable, so such an example might be difficult to find.  Then again, maybe some of the recently constructed examples would suffice?

---

*Edited to add (July '16):* I found an example of a u.p.-semigroup which does not have this triple product property, which lends credence to the belief that the same is true for groups.

Comment: I have at least two interpretations for "the corresponding property": one involving abc and one ab,ac, and bc.  Would you be more explicit about what you seek?  Gerhard "Or Do You Want All?" Paseman, 2016.04.01.

Comment: By "orderable" you mean "left-orderable" or "bi-orderable"?

Comment: Orderable means two-sided orderable.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I clarified that I meant the "triple" product property.

Comment: What are typical examples of u.p. (semi)groups?

Comment: Typical examples are ordered groups.